# check if there is dot in the pandas column values and update the status column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Need to update the status column to 'excep' for which the data in the column 'extr' does not have a dot(.) in pandas.

```
Code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data_df = pd.DataFrame({'typ map': ['D', 'T','A', 'D'],
                         'extr': ['rpt ', 'abc.txt','[test].[att]', 'depot and '],
                         'status': ['vld', '','vld', 'depot and ']
                         })
data_df['status'] = np.where(((data_df['typ map'] =='D') & (data_df[~data_df['extr'].str.contains('.',na=False)])),'excep',data_df.status)

As there is no dot(.) in the 'extr' column for w.r.t column 'typ map', this has to be updated with 'excep'. 
Expected output is as below:
 
    typ map         extr           status
0   D               rpt            excep
1   T               abc.txt 
2   A               [test].[att]    vld
3   D               depot and      excep
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few errors in the code:

- you should use the `regex=False` parameter of [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (`.` matches any character by default).
- you shouldn't slice `data_df` with the output of `str.contains`, it returns a boolean Series.
- `np.where` is not needed, just assign on a slice with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

```
data_df.loc[data_df['typ map'].eq('D')
            &~data_df['extr'].str.contains('.', regex=False, na=False),
           'status'] = 'excep'
```

Output:

```
  typ map          extr status
0       D          rpt   excep
1       T       abc.txt       
2       A  [test].[att]    vld
3       D    depot and   excep
```